# Annotation for various constructors in Lombok?

Tags: java, lombok

I have a class

```
public class Answer<T> {
    private T data;

    public Answer(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Answer() {
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public Answer<T> setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
        return this;
    }
}
```

which I want to simplify with `Lombok`.

If I add annotation `@AllArgsConstructor` than I can't see default constructor.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Answer<T> {
    private T data;

    public Answer<T> setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to have both constructor in `Lombok`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your class is equivalent to:

```
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Data    
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Answer<T> {

    private T data;
}
```

Although strictly speaking this adds `toString`, `equals` and `hashCode` methods on **all** variables.  This can (and often does) cause infinite loops. Be very wary of `@Data`.

`@Accessors(chain = true)` makes the `setter` implementations return `this`, more info [here](http://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Accessors.html).

You can add multiple constructor annotations:

> Unlike most other lombok annotations, the existence of an explicit constructor does not stop these annotations from generating their own constructor.

Note that `@Accessors` is experimental so may be changed/renamed at some future point.

I prefer [`@Builder`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder.html) to `@AllArgsConstructor` as it allows only *required* parameters to be set, whereas a all arguments constructor is all or nothing. It also generates much more readable code, consider

```
new Thing(true, 1, 4, false, 4, 4.0)
```

Versus

```
new Thing.Builder().
    setANamnedProperty(true).
    setAnotherNamnedProperty(1).
    ....
    build();
```

Comment: I'd semi-deprecate `@Accessors` in favor of [configuration](http://projectlombok.org/features/configuration.html). Concerning constructors, I rather use exclusively `@RequiredArgsConstructor`. Combined with Guice, it means, I just declare a field and can use it (no constructor calls in code).

Comment: Didn't know about configuration - that's a shiny new thing. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 13):

Have you tried this?

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
```

Comment: for some reason in my case this creates only the first constructor (no args), and ignores the second one. If I flip the order, the issue is flipped as well...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use both  constructor in Lombok.

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
```

**@AllArgsConstructor** generates a constructor requiring an argument for every field in the annotated class.

So we have the Employee class with two fields:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private int salary;
}
```

When we de-lombok the class, it becomes:

```
public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private int salary;

    public Employee(String name, int salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

---

**@NoArgsConstructor** generates a default constructor with no parameters.

We have the following Employee class:

```
@NoArgsConstructor   
public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private int salary;
}
```

When we look at the generated code, we see that Lombok adds a no-args constructor:

```
public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private int salary;

    public Employee() {
    }
}
```

[More examples](http://www.javabyexamples.com/delombok-allargsconstructor-noargsconstructor-and-requiredargsconstructor/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This should work. Add this annotation as well.

> `@NoArgsConstructor`

@NoArgsConstructor will generate a constructor with no parameters. If this is not possible (because of final fields), a compiler error will result instead, unless @NoArgsConstructor(force = true) is used, then all final fields are initialized with 0 / false / null. For fields with constraints, such as @NonNull fields, no check is generated,so be aware that these constraints will generally not be fulfilled until those fields are properly initialized later. Certain java constructs, such as hibernate and the Service Provider Interface require a no-args constructor. This annotation is useful primarily in combination with either @Data or one of the other constructor generating annotations.